# Checking domain from where my webservice request is being made

Tags: webservices, httprequest, custom-domain

I have several webservice requests being made via APEX to external systems, right now we would like to add the domain from where these requests are being made to our clients firewall. Where can i check this information? The domains that i have discovered are:

From sandbox: csXX.salesforce.com

From production: customDomain.my.salesforce.com

Are these the only domains that can be used or are there more? Can they change?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce URLs can include both *.salesforce.com and *.force.com domains. If you can match with wildcards, that would be ideal, since you can have a few different variants, including domain.my.salesforce.com, domain.visual.force.com, domain--sandboxname.lightning.force.com, domain--sandboxname.csXX.salesforce.com, and others. The only consistently true piece of information for all orgs is that their pages will be located in *.salesforce.com or *.force.com sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use domain object to get the data 
The link is below.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_domain.htm

The domain name changes with each new sandbox or same sandbox when it is refreshed and a new salesforce server is allocated.

It will never change in production, but it will change for your fullcopy or other boxes. To mitigate this issue you may ask your IT team to whitelist the new domain. Generally we whitelist IP not domain for firewall restriction. Whitelisting all salesfore ip is easy and reliable.